# Makefile:76 error when running Darknet on Floydhub

Tags: deep-learning, cloud, darknet

These are my first times of trying to run a project on cloud. My main goal is to train Darknet with my chosen object. I eun the following command:

```
floyd run --gpu --data laurynasg/datasets/face-cfg/2:cfg --data laurynasg/datasets/face-data/1:data --data laurynasg/datasets/face-weights/1:weights "make && ./darknet detector train /cfg/obj.data /cfg/face-yolov3.cfg /weights/darknet53.conv.74"
```

My Makefile started like this:

```
GPU=1
CUDNN=1
OPENCV=0
```

But I get an error:

```
2018-08-19 05:37:13,353 INFO - Run Output:
2018-08-19 05:37:13,362 INFO - Starting services.
2018-08-19 05:37:14,521 INFO - mkdir -p backup
2018-08-19 05:37:14,525 INFO - mkdir -p results
2018-08-19 05:37:14,533 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/convolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/convolutional_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:37:24,114 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/deconvolutional_kernels.cu -o obj/deconvolutional_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:37:32,407 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/activation_kernels.cu -o obj/activation_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:37:40,788 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/im2col_kernels.cu -o obj/im2col_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:37:48,928 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/col2im_kernels.cu -o obj/col2im_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:37:57,081 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/blas_kernels.cu -o obj/blas_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:08,698 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/crop_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:17,205 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/dropout_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:25,262 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/maxpool_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:33,570 INFO - nvcc  -gencode arch=compute_30,code=sm_30 -gencode arch=compute_35,code=sm_35 -gencode arch=compute_50,code=[sm_50,compute_50] -gencode arch=compute_52,code=[sm_52,compute_52] -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ --compiler-options "-Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU" -c ./src/avgpool_layer_kernels.cu -o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:41,781 INFO - gcc -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -shared obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/cuda.o obj/deconvolutional_layer.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/route_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/box.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/layer.o obj/local_layer.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/logistic_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/tree.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/l2norm_layer.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/iseg_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/deconvolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o -o libdarknet.so -lm -pthread  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lstdc++
2018-08-19 05:38:41,848 INFO - ar rcs libdarknet.a obj/gemm.o obj/utils.o obj/cuda.o obj/deconvolutional_layer.o obj/convolutional_layer.o obj/list.o obj/image.o obj/activations.o obj/im2col.o obj/col2im.o obj/blas.o obj/crop_layer.o obj/dropout_layer.o obj/maxpool_layer.o obj/softmax_layer.o obj/data.o obj/matrix.o obj/network.o obj/connected_layer.o obj/cost_layer.o obj/parser.o obj/option_list.o obj/detection_layer.o obj/route_layer.o obj/upsample_layer.o obj/box.o obj/normalization_layer.o obj/avgpool_layer.o obj/layer.o obj/local_layer.o obj/shortcut_layer.o obj/logistic_layer.o obj/activation_layer.o obj/rnn_layer.o obj/gru_layer.o obj/crnn_layer.o obj/demo.o obj/batchnorm_layer.o obj/region_layer.o obj/reorg_layer.o obj/tree.o obj/lstm_layer.o obj/l2norm_layer.o obj/yolo_layer.o obj/iseg_layer.o obj/convolutional_kernels.o obj/deconvolutional_kernels.o obj/activation_kernels.o obj/im2col_kernels.o obj/col2im_kernels.o obj/blas_kernels.o obj/crop_layer_kernels.o obj/dropout_layer_kernels.o obj/maxpool_layer_kernels.o obj/avgpool_layer_kernels.o
2018-08-19 05:38:41,858 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/captcha.c -o obj/captcha.o
2018-08-19 05:38:41,993 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/super.c -o obj/super.o
2018-08-19 05:38:42,098 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/art.c -o obj/art.o
2018-08-19 05:38:42,163 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/tag.c -o obj/tag.o
2018-08-19 05:38:42,270 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/cifar.c -o obj/cifar.o
2018-08-19 05:38:42,436 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/go.c -o obj/go.o
2018-08-19 05:38:43,036 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/rnn.c -o obj/rnn.o
2018-08-19 05:38:43,283 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/segmenter.c -o obj/segmenter.o
2018-08-19 05:38:43,433 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/regressor.c -o obj/regressor.o
2018-08-19 05:38:43,567 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/classifier.c -o obj/classifier.o
2018-08-19 05:38:43,974 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/coco.c -o obj/coco.o
2018-08-19 05:38:44,173 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/yolo.c -o obj/yolo.o
2018-08-19 05:38:44,364 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/detector.c -o obj/detector.o
2018-08-19 05:38:44,699 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/nightmare.c -o obj/nightmare.o
2018-08-19 05:38:44,867 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU -c ./examples/instance-segmenter.c -o obj/instance-segmenter.o
2018-08-19 05:38:45,025 INFO - gcc -Iinclude/ -Isrc/ -DGPU -I/usr/local/cuda/include/ -Wall -Wno-unused-result -Wno-unknown-pragmas -Wfatal-errors -fPIC -Ofast -DGPU obj/captcha.o obj/lsd.o obj/super.o obj/art.o obj/tag.o obj/cifar.o obj/go.o obj/rnn.o obj/segmenter.o obj/regressor.o obj/classifier.o obj/coco.o obj/yolo.o obj/detector.o obj/nightmare.o obj/instance-segmenter.o obj/darknet.o libdarknet.a -o darknet -lm -pthread  -L/usr/local/cuda/lib64 -lcuda -lcudart -lcublas -lcurand -lstdc++  libdarknet.a
2018-08-19 05:38:45,088 INFO - obj/go.o: In function `train_go':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,089 INFO - go.c:(.text+0xf0e): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,089 INFO - obj/rnn.o: In function `vec_char_rnn':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,090 INFO - rnn.c:(.text+0x1996): undefined reference to `cuda_pull_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,090 INFO - obj/segmenter.o: In function `train_segmenter':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,090 INFO - segmenter.c:(.text+0x521): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,090 INFO - obj/regressor.o: In function `train_regressor':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,090 INFO - regressor.c:(.text+0x4d6): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,091 INFO - obj/classifier.o: In function `train_classifier':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,091 INFO - classifier.c:(.text+0x672): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,091 INFO - obj/classifier.o: In function `try_classifier':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,091 INFO - classifier.c:(.text+0x2f66): undefined reference to `cuda_pull_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,092 INFO - obj/detector.o: In function `train_detector':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,092 INFO - detector.c:(.text+0x521): undefined reference to `sync_nets'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,092 INFO - detector.c:(.text+0x58e): undefined reference to `sync_nets'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,092 INFO - detector.c:(.text+0x791): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,092 INFO - detector.c:(.text+0xae8): undefined reference to `sync_nets'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - obj/nightmare.o: In function `optimize_picture':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x42c): undefined reference to `cuda_make_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `forward_network_gpu'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x496): undefined reference to `cuda_pull_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x4ba): undefined reference to `cuda_push_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x4c2): undefined reference to `backward_network_gpu'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,093 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x4d9): undefined reference to `cuda_pull_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0x4e5): undefined reference to `cuda_free'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - obj/nightmare.o: In function `reconstruct_picture':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xa35): undefined reference to `cuda_push_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xa4b): undefined reference to `cuda_make_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xa5a): undefined reference to `forward_network_gpu'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xa70): undefined reference to `cuda_push_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xa9f): undefined reference to `backward_network_gpu'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,094 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xab1): undefined reference to `cuda_pull_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - nightmare.c:(.text+0xabd): undefined reference to `cuda_free'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - obj/instance-segmenter.o: In function `train_isegmenter':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - instance-segmenter.c:(.text+0x531): undefined reference to `train_networks'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `add_bias_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x3ce): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `backward_bias_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,095 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x613): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `adam_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x7ee): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `normalize_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9a7): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `normalize_delta_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0xbc6): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o):tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x124b): more undefined references to `cuda_gridsize' follow
2018-08-19 05:38:45,096 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `softmax_tree':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x42bc): undefined reference to `cuda_make_int_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x42cf): undefined reference to `cuda_make_int_array'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x42fc): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x434a): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4352): undefined reference to `cuda_free'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `softmax_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x44f3): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,097 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `upsample_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4723): undefined reference to `cuda_gridsize'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `scale_bias_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x155): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `backward_scale_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x2c8): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `add_bias_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x415): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,098 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `backward_bias_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x5f1): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `adam_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x84d): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o):tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x9fe): more undefined references to `check_error' follow
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `softmax_tree':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x4368): undefined reference to `cuda_free'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `softmax_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,099 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x454f): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,100 INFO - libdarknet.a(blas_kernels.o): In function `upsample_gpu':
2018-08-19 05:38:45,100 INFO - tmpxft_00000134_00000000-5_blas_kernels.compute_52.cudafe1.cpp:(.text+0x478b): undefined reference to `check_error'
2018-08-19 05:38:45,100 INFO - collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
2018-08-19 05:38:45,100 INFO - Makefile:76: recipe for target 'darknet' failed
2018-08-19 05:38:45,100 INFO - make: *** [darknet] Error 1
```

Some people on the internet say that it is a problem because CUDA folder cannot be found, but I don't think I am in control of that on Floydhub. i have tried a fix suggested in https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/darknet/IBtKSD7vQYE, but nothing has changed. What can I do to fix it?

Comment: You need to include more lines from the compiler output, because the lines you included only say an error has happened, but the details of the error are above those lines.

Comment: True. Fixed the problem